# Access denied while opening PDF on SMB share

Tags: pdf, samba, file-sharing

I can't open a PDF file on a SMB share. (Acrobat Reader tells me: "Access denied").

This problem only concerns to one file in a folder. The other files are accessible w/o troubles.

I don't understand why I can copy this file on my local PC and open it w/o troubles.

Comment: Your question is way to broad, you have to give us more information, if you want to narrow down the possible reasons you cannot access your file.  In it's current form your question cannot be answered due to the number of possible reasons.

Comment: What are most common problems or what information do you need?

Comment: Acrobat Reader tells me your using a Windows machine.  You also indicate your using a Samba share.  Which means I need to know how the Samba share authenticates agaist your Windows infrastructure.  Have you verified the permissions on the file,, on what I presume is Linux, is correct?  Have you verified the user actually does have access to the file on the Windows side?

Comment: Yes, the client runs on Win7. I assume that the server also runs on Win. The weird thing is that I can't open the file, but I can copy it from the share to the desktop and open it there.

Comment: A user can have the permission to copy a file but not open the file on NTFS.  So I will again, ask you to provide us, the permissions on the file.  Be sure to provide us the permissions only displayed in the **advanced** ACL (it has permissions that provide finer control).

Comment: Ok, I will tell you the permissions later...